# Get PostData as in FireBug

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firebug, xul

Anyone, help me, how to get Headers and PostData inside extension, using xpcom/something else?
i cant find functions inside firebug due to it is big codebase... thank you guys

Comment: If you want to find functions within a code base you can always try grep (or something equivalent).

Comment: it is too OOP code :) Very deep , so it takes long time to clarify what is what for...

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want request headers, not response headers. Then you register an observer for the `http-on-modify-request` notification. The general documentation is https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Observer_Notifications#HTTP_requests, a code example can be found under https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Creating_Sandboxed_HTTP_Connections#Handling_cookies. Getting the headers is easy, you simply call `nsIHttpChannel.getRequestHeader()`.

Getting response headers is similar but you need to listen to `http-on-examine-response` notification and probably `http-on-examine-cached-response` as well.

POST data is tricky. You can get the upload stream as `httpChannel.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIUploadChannel).uploadStream`. But the stream can only be read once - it is either you or the code sending data to the server. So you need to replace the stream by something that looks identical but allows you to peek on it - probably nsIInputStreamTee where you set the original stream as source and nsIPipe as sink. Not sure whether this is the approach chosen by Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

Wladimir is right on for the headers. For the POST data, here's a couple of code snippets with a little more detail:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Miscellaneous#Getting_postData_of_a_webpage