# How to track HTTP responses of a page through an Add-on using Add-on builder

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-sdk, content-script

I want to create an add-on which tracks the HTTP responses of each page. How can i include this code in my contentscriptFile. Along with this i also want to track the meta tags. This can be done by using `document.getElementsByTagName('meta');` But this gives the mets tags of the current page but not the page which is opened. how can i achieve this functionality through add-on builder.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't something that can be done in a content script, it doesn't have that kind of privileges (and it is simply too short-lived for that). You need to put that code into your extension files, e.g. `main.js`. See [Get PostData as in FireBug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168729/get-postdata-as-in-firebug/6250221#6250221) for the general approach. You will need to register an observer for the `http-on-examine-response` topic, [`observer-service` package](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.6/packages/api-utils/observer-service.html) can be used for that (note: low-level API, you are leaving the supported APIs of the Add-on SDK here).

Comment: i tried the example given in  [Firefox extension observing response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812604/firefox-extension-observing-response) but i am not getting any output